# “TemplateDoesNotExist” after package installed

Tags: django

Could any one help me to figure out why ?

I just followed the structure of tutorial , and installed the package called django-polls to my project called mysite successfully. But it returned "TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/" after running the server.

Following is What I have done:

```
1.pip install /django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
2.modifed the settings.py in mysite project
3.modifed the urls.py in mysite project
4.python manage.py runserver
```

## settings.py in mysite project:

```
 ...
 TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
 ...
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
)
...
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
...
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader', # <--
)
```

Comment: You need to share your code.

Comment: may the code shared enough for this question?  Do appreciate, if any guideline could give for I am really a new starter.